# Display hourly based data for 24 hour in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to display the hourly based report for the last 24 hour. I have tried but the problem is that it will display count only where particular hour contains data.

But I want to display count for an hour and if count not found then display 0 over there.

```
select 
    datepart(hour, upload_date) as [hour], count(*)
from 
    tbl_stories
where 
    upload_date > getdate() - 1
group by 
    datepart(hour, upload_date)
```

Output:

```
hour    count
-------------
11      2
16      1
17      1
```

but I want to get a record in the following way.

```
hour   count
-------------
1       0
2       0
3       5
.
.
.
.
24       1
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with both Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL. These are different DBMS products with different solutions. Remove the extraneous tag.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `value()` clause to generate all the hours and then use `left join`:

```
select v.hh, count(s.upload_date)
from (values (0), (1), . . . (23)
     ) v(hh) left join
     tbl_stories s
     on datepart(hour, s.upload_date) = v.hh and
        s.upload_date > getdate() - 1
group by v.hh
order by v.hh;
```

Note that hours go from 0 to 23.

If you don't want to list out the hours, a convenient generation method is a recursive CTE:

```
with hours as (
      select 1 as hh
      union all
      select hh + 1
      from hours
      where hh < 23
     )
select h.hh, count(s.upload_date)
from hours h
     tbl_stories s
     on datepart(hour, s.upload_date) = h.hh and
        s.upload_date > getdate() - 1
group by h.hh
order by h.hh;
```